# Python unit test for nested if statement

Tags: python, unit-testing, if-statement, nested

So I've been posting unit test questions because I'm trying to get good at them. I'll try to be as clear as possible. Below I have a nested if statement, I want to mock the input for the `difficulty` variable and check for the stdout if the condition is met.

here is my run code..

```
def main():
    print("''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''")
    print("''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''")
    print("''' \t\t\t\t '''")
    print("''' \t\t\t\t '''")
    print("''' \t   Pirate Games\t\t '''")
    print("''' \tStart a new game?\t '''")
    print("''' \t\t\t\t '''")
    print("''' \t\t\t\t '''")
    print("''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''")
    print("''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''")

    newGame = input("").lower()

    if newGame == "yes" or "y":

        print("1.Scallywag\n2.Crew\n3.Pirate")
        difficulty = input("Choose ye toughness!")

        if difficulty == "1":
            print("TEST")

    elif newGame == "no" or "n":
        print("Goodbye! Come Again")

    else:
        print("Enter correct input!")
```

Now here's my unit test, but this is only for the first If Statement, which works fine. I don't know how to go about doing the second one. Any help is appreciated, thank you all in advance.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import io
import sys

from RunFile import main

class GetInputTest(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch('builtins.input', return_value='yes')
  def test_output(self,m):
      saved_stdout = sys.stdout
      try:
          out = io.StringIO()
          sys.stdout = out
          main()
          output = out.getvalue().strip()
          self.assertEqual(output, "1.Scallywag\n2.Crew\n3.Pirate")
      finally:
          sys.stdout = saved_stdout


if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

Comment: If you're running 3.4, [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) is a cleaner way of, well, redirecting stdout - no more try/finally ugliness.  Even if you're on 3.3, you may want to add such a context manager to your toolbox if you find yourself doing it often in testing like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) argument to `patch` to make `input` return `"yes"` the first time its called, and `"1"` the second time:

```
class GetInputTest(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch('builtins.input', side_effect=["yes", "1"])
  def test_output(self,m):
      saved_stdout = sys.stdout
      try:
          out = io.StringIO()
          sys.stdout = out
          main()
          output = out.getvalue().strip()
          # Make sure TEST appears at the end, in addition to the original list of items.
          self.assertEqual(output, "1.Scallywag\n2.Crew\n3.Pirate\nTEST")

      finally:
          sys.stdout = saved_stdout
```

Comment: It works but only if I remove the stdout in the beginning (all the start a new game stuff) how can I bypass that.

Comment: @Salce__ You'd either need to adjust your test case to only assert that the text you care about is in the total output, rather than test for equality: `self.assertIn("1.Scallywag\n2.Crew\n3.Pirate\nTEST", output)`, or refactor your original code so that the welcome message is in a separate function from the code the handles the user input. Then you could *just* test the user-input handling function.